# Rails Many-to-Many Relantionship Dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and a Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What should I do if I want a `User` to be able to fund `Projects`, and a `Project` can be funded by many `Users`?

This would mean I get a Many-to-many relationship, and I would need an additional intermediate table. Call it `user_projects`:

```
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

But how do I cope with the previous relationship I had between the models before I implemented the third one?

How do I know which project belongs to which user if I have the intermediate table?

Would I modify the tables the following way?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, through: :user_project, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: user_project
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not you need an intermediate table depends on if there is any associated data you need to store with the user/project pair -- such as a dollar amount or date info or role, etc.

If you don't need to store anything else, then just use a HABTM relationship.  Otherwise, your final solution would be the way to go.

I personally don't like the choice of 'user_project' as it's too close to the HABTM's 'users_projects'.  Perhaps something like ProjectMember or ProjectFunder or Funding would be better, but it kind of depends on what extra data you need to store.

Comment: what Philip said. And your relationship model is fine, exactly what's called for. I'd store the project "owner" on the project itself (:owner_id, class_name: "User") And then you can treat funders as a different quasi "type".

Comment: It basically needs to work like a crowdfunding site. So I would need to store in the intermediate table an amount of money, so no HABTM. Out of curiosity, how would you go about implementing a ProjectFunder table? Wouldn't it still be similar to what I wrote? It would need a user_id and project_id to act as FK's and an amount field to store the money. Correct me if mistaken. (thanks for replying Philip)

Comment: Yep, it would still need user_id and project_id and then whatever else you needed to store.  You're on the right track.

Comment: @MBHNYC: I am trying to implement what you described but I feel a bit stuck. I've tried googling but no success so far

Comment: which part?  you can name associations anything you want, as long as rails knows where to find the source table.

Comment: The part with having a "type" field in the projects table. I believe that's called Inheritance, and while I do understand the concepts, I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Doh. The HABTM also uses an intermediate table, that you have to create in a separate migration too. In a many-to-many relation you will always need an intermediate table.